# How to Integrate Testing a Controller, which inside that controller, methods gets token from another site

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing

I'm setting up an API which it gets authenticated to another server through JWT.
one of Controller's methods I want to test, gets the token from an external site.
how can I test this method?

I made a Test server and tried to mimic the website action which providing tokens.i can access this `Test Server` through Test Methods but I can't get to it from the actual controller.

here is my Test Server setup method
`MockedController` is the Controller supposed to provide toke and is working fine and I can get tokens from test units.
`AuthController` is the Controller supposed to test.

```cs
var server = new TestServer(
                new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment(TestConstants.EnvironmentName)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(TestConstants.MockAddress)
                .ConfigureTestServices(config =>
                {
                    config.AddOptions();
                    config.AddMvc()
                       .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(AuthController).Assembly)
                        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(MockedTokenController).Assembly)
                        ;

                    config.AddSingleton<MockedTokenController>();
                    config.BuildServiceProvider();
                }));
            server.BaseAddress = new Uri(TestConstants.MockAddress);
            server.CreateHandler();
            _client = server.CreateClient();
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(TestConstants.MockAddress);// I tried with and without this line
```

Here is the test method which is failing

```cs
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/Auth/Login");
            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
```

Here is the AuthController Login Method code

```cs
[HttpGet("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(){
         var token = await _authService.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync();
         return Ok(token);
}
```

here is the AuthService code which is called from `AuthController`

```cs
public async Task<string> GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(){
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       var response = await client.SendAsync(request, 
       HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       return token;
}
```

extra information.
test method for mocked controller works fine.
it seems the problem is in second step usage of the mocked controller. the first step works fine. I mean I can access the mocked controller from Test unit at first step but when I try to access it through the Main controller(AuthController), I can't get to it

Comment: Code is too tightly coupled to implementation concerns to allow for components to be mocked to isolate it from 3rd party dependencies. Because `HttpClient` is created manually there is no way to replace its handler to fake the requests. Have you considered mocking the auth service itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too tightly coupled to implementation concerns to allow for components to be mocked to isolate it from 3rd party dependencies. Because `HttpClient` is created manually there is no way to replace its handler to fake the requests.

Consider mocking the auth service itself that is injected into the controller under test.

```
For example

//...

var token = "{fake token here}";
var authService = Mock.Of<IAuthService>(_ =>
    _.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync == Task.FromResult(token)
);

config.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(authService);

//...
```